# Data not refreshing on datagridview C#

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'd make DataGridView in C# using LINQ. Then, when user DoubleClick the data on it, it will pop up form for editing data. What I want is, after I Close the popup the data in DataGridView is automatically refreshing.

```
private void cooperationsDataGridView_CellDoubleClick(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            frmKoperasi frm = new frmKoperasi (cooperationsDataGridView.CurrentRow.Cells["id"].Value.ToString());
            frm.FormClosed += delegate { refresh(sender,e); };
            frm.Show();                                            
        }

private void refresh(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       this.listKoperasi_Load(sender, e);           
   }

private void listKoperasi_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        page = page - 1;
        var query = (from c in db_cooperations.cooperations
                     orderby c.id
                     select c).Skip(numberOfObjectsPerPage * page).Take(numberOfObjectsPerPage);

        cooperationsBindingSource.DataSource = query;           
    }
```

But after I close the edit form, the data is not refreshing. What could be wrong?

Comment: Do your data classes implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`? And is this LINQ to Objects? LINQ to SQL? LINQ to Entity Framework?

Comment: I'm using LINQ TO SQL. There are "public partial class cooperation : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged", is it what you meant ?

Answer (score 0):

just add `.ToList()`

```
cooperationsBindingSource.DataSource = query.ToList();
```

Comment: I'm not so certain that is the problem with the Popup not updating the data as seen in the main data grid.

Answer (score 0):

At the end, I just rewrite everything from beginning, and just going right. Don't know why its happen :D