# DataGridView not refreshing instantaneously

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have created a `DataGridView` in `C#`.

```
private void SomeFunc()
{ 
    DataGridView errorDataGrid = new System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView();

    // Set properties for DataGrid View
    // ..
    // ..

    // Add to the panel
    somePanel.Controls.Add(this.errorDataGrid);
}

private void ShowOnGrid(string _message)
{
    // create a new row and add a text to it
    DataGridViewRow newRow = new DataGridViewRow();
    newRow.CreateCells(this.errorDataGrid, _message);

   // add this row to grid
   this.errorDataGrid.Rows.Add(newRow);
   // and scroll the bar to the newly added row, [currentRow = 0 initially]
   this.errorDataGrid.FirstDisplayedScrollingRowIndex = currentRow++;
}
```

The problem is the data (_message) is not displayed immediately after adding to grid. Instead it is shown all of a sudden, at the end of program

```
ShowOnGrid("My Message to show - 1")
ShowOnGrid("My Message to show - 2")
ShowOnGrid("My Message to show - 3")
ShowOnGrid("My Message to show - 4")
ShowOnGrid("My Message to show - 5")
ShowOnGrid("My Message to show - 6")
// End of program
```

So all messages are displayed at the End of my Program.
**Am i missing something ? Or is something wrong  in above program ?**

---

I referred to following, but couldn't find anything significant:

- [DataGridView not refreshing and propagating data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17382964/datagridview-not-refreshing-and-propagating-data)
- [DataGridView not Refreshing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21028666/datagridview-not-refreshing)
- [Data not refreshing on datagridview C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445985/data-not-refreshing-on-datagridview-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0):

Your `ShowOnGrid` method is called on the UI thread. So, when the method, for instance, `CallShowOnGrid` is called which in turn calls `ShowOnGrid` method, the UI thread is blocked. It will only be refreshed (to call it that) once all `ShowOnGrid` methods have been executed.

If you can show the method which calls the `ShowOnGrid` method and a little more context, someone can provide a solution.

Comment: Hey, I corrected it by putting this after adding a row to grid. I added `dataGrid.Refresh()`